# How to Export Mail Item into Excel file

Tags: excel, email, export

I need your help to to export e-mail body to Excel File.

The Excel file should contain the following fields:

1. S\N.
2. RMA Number
3. Arrived Date to RMA site 1st level
4. Forward Date from RMA 1st level to 2nd level
5. RMA Finding 1st level
6. Current Status
7. Current Assign Team

All the above data located in the email body.

Here is an Example of the email body:

```
    [ https://jira.sandisk.com/browse/CSSFIRSTLEVELFA-571?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel ]

Tony Wang updated CSSFIRSTLEVELFA-571:
--------------------------------------

    Summary:  RMA#60022453 --> **RMA Number**(QSS RMA#CD1S0064) GS2 unit Failed:Quanta F5-APPLE-20130125(1pcs, without FA log files)  (was:  RMA#xxxxxx (QSS RMA#xxxxxx) GS2 unit Failed:Quanta F5-APPLE-20130125(1pcs, without FA log files))

Goods arrived at QSS/RMA site on: Feb 5th, 2013 -->**Arrived Date to RMA site 1st level**

1st Level FA findings: 
AI result: Pass --> **RMA Finding 1st level**
X-Ray result: Pass 

SKU# SD5SG2-256G-1052E
S/N:124310409056 --> **Serial Number**

QSMC/F5 - Apple feedback NG information:HDFU1 --> **Status** Units moved to SanDisk 2nd level FA Lab (Feb 6th, 2013) --> **Forward Date from RMA 1st level to 2nd level**

All the below information is unnecessarily..

>  RMA#60022453(QSS RMA#CD1S0064) GS2 unit Failed:Quanta 
> F5-APPLE-20130125(1pcs, without FA log files)
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> ------------------------------
>
>                 Key: CSSFIRSTLEVELFA-571
>                 URL: https://jira.sandisk.com/browse/CSSFIRSTLEVELFA-571
>             Project: CSS - OSS and 1st level FA
>          Issue Type: RMA-FA
>         Environment: MATIS
>            Reporter: Ming Li
>            Assignee: Ming Li
>
> S/N#124310409056 history step: 
> 1. OSS request date:1/24
> 2. OSS visit date:1/25. (124310409056) error code:7080; apply for RMA. 
> SKU#SD5SL2-256G-1205E

--
This message is automatically generated by JIRA.
-
If you think it was sent incorrectly contact one of the administrators: https://jira.sandisk.com/secure/Administrators.jspa
-
For more information on JIRA, see: http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira
```

Comment: Don't you mind sharing with us at least a relevant piece of your efforts - just in support of [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)